# How can I group two Prometheus timeseries on a new label using promql?

Tags: prometheus, alert, promql, observability

Let's say I have two prometheus timeseries, `ts1` and `ts2`. I would like to combine them to create a new timeseries, `tsK` which will have a label inside for the consitutent timeseries, i.e.

`tsK{inner_ts="ts1"}` should yield the original ts1 timeseries and

`tsK{inner_ts="ts2"}` should yield the original ts2 timeseries.

Is there a way to do this using PromQL? I have tried using:

`ts1 + ts2` , `ts1 or ts2` and `(ts1,ts2)`  but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following PromQL:

```
label_join(ts1, "inner_ts", "", "__name__") or label_join(ts2, "inner_ts", "", "__name__")
```

Comment: Tried this, it seems to only return a single TS

Comment: Which one, ts1 or ts2?  Has the inner_ts label been created? Is the value correct?

Comment: Just ts1 is rendered. The `inner_ts` label is not created

Comment: So the "label_join" command didn't work, check to see if something is wrong. Have you used two underline characters in the "__name__"?

Comment: Yes, I copied your command verbatim

Comment: I don't have any other idea, it worked pretty well for me in Prometheus 2.26.0.